# In PHPStorm, while using Live Template, how can I replace underscore with a space?

Tags: phpstorm, laravel-blade, intellij-13, live-templates

I am using Live Templates in PHPStorm to easily create blocks of code using variables I define. I created a live template block that creates a group of elements for a text form field using the blade templating engine.

```
<!--- $VALUE$ Field --->
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('$NAME$', '$VALUE$') }}
    {{ Form::text('$NAME$', null, []) }}
</div>
```

I set up the variables so that I can enter the NAME variable first in all lowercase letters, and it will then automatically fill in the VALUE variable for me while capitalizing the first letter.

[image]

Here's an example of how that works out when the name variable is a single word:

```
<!--- Address Field --->
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('address', 'Address') }}
    {{ Form::text('address', null, []) }}
</div>
```

This works great, but I run into a problem when the field name has two words. I prefer to use underscores between two words for the NAME attribute, and unfortunately that underscore appears in the VALUE variable as well.

```
<!--- Zip_code Field --->
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('zip_code', 'Zip_code') }}
    {{ Form::text('zip_code', null, []) }}
</div>
```

I can't find a expression in the live template variables setup that allows me to replace an underscore with a space. Ideally I would like to keep the first letter capitalized while also replacing any underscores with spaces for the VALUE variable. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`underscoresToSpaces(String)` should do the thing. Like:

```
capitalize(underscoresToSpaces(NAME))
```